# SonarQube Build Breaker version update for Multiple Projects in TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, sonarqube

Is there a way to SonarQube Build breaker for multiple projects in TFS. As we have more than 100 projects in TFS, now we are updating the SonarQube Build Breaker version and we do not want to go each Build Definition and want to automate it.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to update the build definitions with the new breaker?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a script using TFS REST APIs to update build process task version.

[Get Build Definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1)

In this link you have do documentation to use the TFS rest apis.

The JSON path to find the version spec of the task is

> rootObject.process.phases[0].steps[sonarqube build braker task
>   id].versionSpec